# how do i execute this @get...@Query snippet correctly?

Tags: android, json, android-studio

```
@GET("comments?_sort=id&_order=desc&_limit=5&_page={pageNumber}")

Call<java.util.ArrayList<ImgRepo>>fetchNewData (@Path("pageNumber") int pageNumber);
```

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

To use Retrofit calls you first have to create a Call object, then execute it's enqueue() method and after that handle the callback, something like this:

```
Call<List<ImgRepo>> call = YourServiceClass.fetchNewData(number);

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ImgRepo>>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<List<ImgRepo>> call, Response<List<ImgRepo>> response) {
        ArrayList<ImgRepo> myData = response.body();
        //Handle success
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<List<ImgRepo> call, Throwable t) {
        // handle failure
      }
    });
```

I recommend you check out this tutorial for more info: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-retrofit-2/